# Operator cannot be applied to operands of type string and int

Tags: c#

Error:

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type string and int.

In my case 'details[0].max' Consists of value 0.0 like this.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details[0].customsalary) && (details[0].max) <= 0 && (details[0].max) <= 0)
{
    _jobdetailsmodel.Salary = details[0].customsalary;
}
```

if value of details[0].max is 0.0 and details[0].min is 0.0 then condition should become true.

Comment: What is the type of `details[0].max`?

Comment: details[0].max of type string.

Comment: So use `Convet.ToSingle(details[0].max);`

Comment: Why are members such as `.customsalary` and `.max` that conceptually are amounts, i.e. numbers, declared as `string`? Of course you can parse these strings into `decimal` or similar (see many answers below), but it feels like these properties should be of type `decimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly cast `details[0].max` to a number, something like

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details[0].customsalary) && decimal.Parse(details[0].max) <= 0)
```

depending on the expected type of `details[0].max`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that 'details[0].max' is string type So please cast it it to Double as:

```
 Convert.ToDouble(details[0].max)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is down to your .max variables likely being strings. The below  code should be enough to get your if statement to work by converting them to integers in the if statement.
I would recommend however potentially reviewing your code and maybe converting these variables to integers in order to avoid having to convert their values at all.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details[0].customsalary) && Convert.ToInt32(details[0].max) <= 0 && Convert.ToInt32(details[0].max) <= 0)
{
    _jobdetailsmodel.Salary = details[0].customsalary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Details[0].max is a string, therefor you need to convert to int, the below code allows for incorrectly formatted strings, where int.Parse will throw an exception if the string is invalid:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details[0].customsalary) && 
                int.TryParse(details[0].max, out var max) && 
                int.TryParse(details[0].min, out var min) &&
                max <= 0 && min <= 0)
            {
                _jobdetailsmodel.Salary = details[0].customsalary;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`details` is array of what ? And `max`, it's an `int`, a `double`, something else ?

There is an example of a `Detail` class:

```
public class Detail1
{
    public string CustomSalary { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public decimal Max2 { get; set; }
}
```

It could be :

```
public class Detail2
{
    public string CustomSalary { get; set; }
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string Max2 { get; set; }
}
```

> Please be more specific

using `Detail2` class, you can use `Parse` extension methods (numeric types has this extension method):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(detail[0].CustomSalary) 
    && int.Parse(details[0].Max) <= 0 
    && decimal.Parse(details[0].Max2 <= 0.0m))
{
    //....
}
```

You can use `System.Convert` class too:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(detail[0].CustomSalary) 
    && Convert.ToInt(details[0].Max) <= 0 
    && Convert.ToDecimal(details[0].Max2 <= 0.0m))
{
    //....
}
```

And if you're not sure there's any value (in `details[0]`), you can add `?` after `details[0]` and/or use `TryParse` extension method:

```
int.TryParse(details[0].Max, out int max);
decimal.TryParse(details[0]?.Max2, out decimal max2);

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(detail[0]?.CustomSalary) 
    && max <= 0
    && max2 <= 0.0m)
{
    //....
}
```

I this case, you don't know the type of `Max` and `Max2` properties. (it can be a simple `object`)